# Python 3 http.server: specify accepted content types?

Tags: python-3.x, server, httpserver

I have an http.server running with Python 3 that only accepts POST requests.  However, we want to specify the accepted/expected content type as `application/json` and not accept other data types.

The approach I am using is this currently:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class POSTProcessor(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    # other code here...

    def do_POST(self):
        if self.headers['Content-Type'].lower() != 'application/json':
            self.send_error(400, explain="Only content of type application/json is accepted")
        else:
            # do something with the POST data
```

... which works pretty well for my needs, as it returns a `400 Bad Request` error with an explanation.  However, this has a prerequisite that the endpoint client making the `POST` request actually sends a `Content-Type` header (and if you're making direct `curl` requests like I am for testing, this isn't a guarantee).

The problem I have here is that I don't know how to actually tell endpoint clients what data type the server accepts.  I can always enforce that the people POSTing data are always specifying the headers, but that can be... problematic... if they aren't going to write up their own custom data submission method.

Is there a way to have this python HTTP request handler tell clients what content types the server will accept for POST requests?